# Bad image quality after resizing/scaling bitmap from IP Camera

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have been working on tensorflow object detection API on Android from quite sometime using the Android Camera2 API and never faced any issue scaling the image to the required 300x300 size for Tensorflow Mobilenet SSD model using the code provided in the tensorflow android sample git repository to resize the image after it is captured by the Android device.

Currently instead of Android device camera i am using an IP camera which captures a high quality 24bit JPEG image(2304x1296) resolution which when i scale it down to 300x300 using the Bitmap.createScaledBitmap function on Android gives a distorted Image.

Is there any helpful Android library or any other resizing technique which i can use to overcome this image distortion issue will be helpfull.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are some other people having issues with the resize function: e.g. [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-tensorflows-tf-image-resize-stole-60-days-of-my-life-aba5eb093f35)

Answer (score -2):

Consider 
import org.tensorflow.demo.env.ImageUtils;

such as
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/demo/CameraActivity.java